# How to access local variables in an outer function in R?

Tags: r, nested

Is there any way to access and modify the x in f from within g? Seems like a copy is made.

```
f<-function() {
    x<-1
    g <- function(y) {
        x<-x+1 # how to access the x above?
        return(x)
    }
    r<-g(1)
    print(x)
    print(r)
}
f()
```

Edit 1: using <<- seems to work!

Comment: Maybe try: `x <<- x + 1`, more info at `?assignOps`

Comment: Don't do this. Pass `x` as a parameter and do `x <- g(1, x)`.